# Switch between multiple JFrames

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

I'm relatively new to Java and I'm trying to make some kind of quiz. I created 3 JFrames, all in the same package. On my main frame, there are two buttons (one for the english version and the other one for the german version). I want to switch JFrames after pressing these buttons (so that I can, by pressing "English", see and interact with my english quiz frame). Looking it up didn't help me the slightest, because I'm not really experienced with it. Is it even possible to do it like this? If not, how could I do it?

Answer (score 5):

The standard approach is to use the [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which allows you to use the same JFrame as you populate it with different things at different points in your application. So initially, your JFrame would show the loading screen, then the user presses a button and you load a new set of components without discarding the current JFrame you have. In some cases, you might also need to make some size adjustments.

It is difficult to say without seeing any code, but usually, what is done is that you do something like so:

```
new Frame(args);
this.dispose();
```

The code above assumes that the constructor of `Frame` takes care of launching and making the components visible. The `this.dispose();` disposes of the current `JFrame` (assuming your class extends `JFrame`).

Answer (score 4):

You have two buttons in your frame 1 right?  So first, double click the button which says "English". Lets say the variable name for that button is jButton1. Inside that button type this.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
    this.dispose();
    EnglishFrame eng = new EnglishFrame();
    eng.setVisible(true);
}
```

Then double click the other button which says "German"  (jButton2). Inside that type this.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
        this.dispose();
        GermanFrame german = new GermanFrame();
        german.setVisible(true);
    }
```

this.dispose() - This will cause the jFrame window to close

Then you create an object of the other two forms. (In your case the form for English and Germany)

.setVisible(true) - This will show you the form.

Answer (score 2):

Create a single Jframe window. After that create [JPanels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) with all the compenents such as buttons, textfields and labels you want. Make sure the panel is the same size as your Jframe. Panel's work about the same as JFrame's, code wise.

This code will stitch everything together for you:

```
    panel.setSize(Jframe.getSize())   //That wont
    panel.add(button);  //Just remember you need to add more code to position the buttons correctly. 
                        //If you using netbeans builder:
                        //You just have to use this one line in the constructor/intialiser method
    frame.add(panel);   //This will add the panel to the Jframe/Window
                        //No need to add extra code for positioning.
```

If you want to swap between the panels. In the button press method, use this

```
    frame.setContentPane(panel); //panel = panel you want to change too.
    frame.repaint();             //Ensures that the frame swaps to the next panel and doesn't get stuck.
    frame.revalidate();          //Ensures that the frame swaps to the next panel and doesn't get stuck.
```

When you first start the java application you have to set the content pane or else it will appear as a blank window.

```
     frame.setContentPane(panel);   //Starting Panel
     frame.setVisible(true);        //Make the frame visible
```

Sorry if the explanation is bad, I don't have enough time to explain it fully.